# SciPy Parabolic Cylinder D and Complex Arguments

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy

I'm trying to use the Parabolic Cylinder D function from SciPy and am having trouble with complex arguments.  Sample code to produce the error is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy
import scipy.special as special
# test real numbers
test = 0.735759
A = test - special.pbdv(1,2)[0]
print A
# test complex numbers.
test = 9.43487e-16+1j*5.1361
A = test - special.pbdv(3,-1j)[0]
print A
```

The error I get is:

```
---> 19 A = test - special.pbdv(3,-1j)[0]
     20 print A
     21 

TypeError: ufunc 'pbdv' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be 
safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

[From the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) it looks like the function is simply not defined to work with complex arguments.  Other scipy functions (like the Bessel function jv) explicitly state they accept complex arguments, so I don't think I am wrong in my reading of the error.

My follow up question: Is there an implementation of the Parabolic Cylinder D function in python that accepts complex arguments?  I've tried constructing my own from [Abramowitz and Stegun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_cylinder_function) but I can't seem to get it to agree with Mathematica.  Suggestions would be appreciated.  My google skills haven't uncovered anything.

Edit:
[Question is similar to the question here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/24074/simulation-of-parabolic-cylinder-function-ua-x-for-complex-arguments).

Comment: FWIW: `mpmath` has several flavors of parabolic cylinder functions, including `pcfd(n, z)`, which accepts complex `z`.    It is quite slow, but since it is part of `mpmath`, you can increase the precision to be as high as you like (or have the patience for).  If nothing else, you could use it to check your implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't understand why the scipy implementation of the function doesn't accept complex arguments, all the functions under the hood accept complex arguments.

I managed to get the function defined in [Abramowitz and Stegun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_cylinder_function) working.  I am not sure what was wrong with my previous attempts.  I am sure there is a better way to write the function, but here is my implementation for using the Parabolic Cylinder D function in python for complex values:

```
import numpy
import scipy.special as special

PI = numpy.pi

def y1(a,z):
    return numpy.exp(-0.25*(z**2.0))*special.hyp1f1(0.5*a+0.25,0.5,0.5*(z**2.0))

def y2(a,z):
    return z*numpy.exp(-0.25*(z**2.0))*special.hyp1f1(0.5*a+0.75,1.5,0.5*(z**2.0))

def U(a,z):
    zeta = 0.5*a+0.25
    return (1/numpy.sqrt(PI))*(1/(2.0**zeta))*(numpy.cos(PI*zeta)*special.gamma(0.5-zeta)*y1(a,z) \
    -numpy.sqrt(2)*numpy.sin(PI*zeta)*special.gamma(1-zeta)*y2(a,z))


def ParabolicCylinderD(v,z):
    b = -v-0.5
    return U(b,z)
```

Edit: This doesn't work if the index is negative.  Dunno why.  I've switched to Warren's suggestion of MPmath above.  It is fast enough for my needs.